# Получить список индексов списка по условию

Tags: python, list

Есть список, состоящий из целочисленных значений:

```
list = [19,31,5,6,2,11,5,32,25,1]
```

Необходимо получить другой список, состоящий из индексов тех элементов списка list, которые больше 10.

```
list_ind = [0,1,5,7,8]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[i for i, v in enumerate(my_list) if v > 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Берёте создаёте список `list_ind`. В цикле `for` идёте по элементам списка `some_list` (`list` - слово зарезервированное языком, лучше его не использовать для идентификаторов(названий переменных, функций, классов и тд. и тп.)), заодно в цикле храните переменную `index` и увеличиваете её каждую итерацию цикла.  И если некий `elem` (который представляет из себя один из элементов `some_list`) больше чем 10, то делаете `list_ind.append(index)`.

Вот и всё.

P.S. Код не пишу, ибо вопрос элементарнейший и если вы начали программировать на питоне, вы должны представлять, как реализовывать подобные вещи!

Answer (score 1):

Код:

```
mylist_begin = [19,31,5,6,2,11,5,32,25,1]
mylist_end = []

index = 0

for x in mylist_begin:
    if x > 10:
        mylist_end.append(index)
    index += 1
print(mylist_end)
```

Не называйте,пожалуйста,переменную list.Это имя зарезервировано в python